# SQL doesn't work using a column returns from subquery in group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I need to run a query like below but it doesn't recognize SHOWNDATE. Why this is happening?

The query was simplified to be clear:

```
select  PYNAME,
        SHOWNDATE=(SELECT MAX(OUTCOMETIME) FROM A where A.ID=B.ID),
        count(PYSUBJECTID)
from B
group by PYNAME,
         SHOWNDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

I think On Select clause write AS SHOWNDATE
SHOWNDATE = is not right.

```
select
PYNAME,
(SELECT MAX(OUTCOMETIME) FROM A where A.ID=B.ID) AS SHOWNDATE,
count(PYSUBJECTID)
from B
group by PYNAME,SHOWNDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on Scott's schema which shows how to do that:

```
SQL> select b.deptno,
  2         (select max(a.sal) from emp a where b.deptno = a.deptno) as showsal,
  3         count(b.empno)
  4  from emp b
  5  group by b.deptno;

    DEPTNO    SHOWSAL COUNT(B.EMPNO)
---------- ---------- --------------
        30       2850              6
        20       3000              3
        10       5000              3

SQL>
```

Or, applied to your query:

```
select  b.pyname,
        (select max(a.outcometime) from a where a.id = b.id) showndate,
        count(b.pysubjectid)
from b
group by b.pyname;
```

Don't forget to apply table aliases to all columns!

Answer (score 0):

ALIAS (in this case SHOWNDATE) is not a valid identifier but it is for the result set from the subquery. ALIASES are used for convenience...no one wants "SELECT MAX(OUTCOMETIME) FROM A where A.ID=B.ID" as column name.

```
select 
PYNAME
,SHOWNDATE
,COUNT
from (
select   PYNAME
    ,(SELECT MAX(OUTCOMETIME) FROM A where A.ID=B.ID) SHOWNDATE
    ,count(PYSUBJECTID) COUNT
from B
 Group by PYNAME
)
group by  PYNAME
     ,SHOWNDATE
     ,COUNT
```